# Download PDF File inside an Iframe is not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, iframe

I have a post web method that generate a pdf file and returns it to the client. I call to this method using a form submit in a new tab using target="_blank", so the pdf opens in the new tab using the PDF Viewer tools of Chrome. Everything is working correct with this implementation, and I can download the pdf file:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

But now i want to open it inside an iframe instead of a new tab. I have this in HTML:

```
<form id="form2" method="post" target="my_iframe" action="">
    <input type="hidden" name="wsInputs" id="wsInputs" />
</form>

<iframe style="width: 100%; height:600px" name="my_iframe" src=""></iframe>
```

When a button is clicked, i do this in typescript:

```
 const form = document.getElementById("form2") as HTMLFormElement;
 const input = document.getElementById("wsInputs") as HTMLInputElement;
 input.value = JSON.stringify(wsPDFInputs);
 form.action = endpoint + "api/v1/downloads/get-pdf";
 form.submit();
```

This works correct, and inside the iframe the document is opened and it works:
[image: PDF opened inside the iframe]

But, when i click on download button, it does not work. This is what it happens when the file explorer is opened:

[image: File explorer]

I do not know why is this happening. In Firefox for example it is working, but not in Chrome. Also, if I click the print icon and I select "save as pdf" works too.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** This is the result of the request that generates the pdf:
[image: result 1]

[image]

Maybe the problem is the response, looks like an html document instead of the pdf file, i do not know why. But the response is the same when target _blank is set.

Comment: Look in the console. You may see an error message

Comment: @mplungjan No, there is no errors in the console.

Comment: Interesting that Chrome suggests the file name `get-pdf.json`. Can you check in the network panel, what requests are actually happening here? My guess would be that Chrome probably tries to make a second request for that endpoint (maybe not even using POST), and that it actually responds with some JSON then.

Comment: @CBroe No, there is no additional requests in network tab. Only the one that gets the pdf first. I updated my question with the result of the request. I see the response is directly a html document, instead of only the pdf file. Maybe is this the problem? Thanks for the answer

Comment: Looks like your API request does not actually return a PDF in the first place, but an HTML document that contains an `embed` element. Can't see in that screenshot though whether that embed tries to load the PDF via an HTTP URL, or a data URI.

Comment: @CBroe the API is a .NET Web API that returns a HttpResponseMessage with the pdf in the content as ByteArrayContent. Where is that information shown in network panel (about the load of the pdf)? But I still not understand why it is working in a new tab but not in an iframe, I check and the response is the same. Thanks for your answer again

Comment: _"Where is that information shown in network panel (about the load of the pdf)?"_ - looks like there isn't one, and that the API actually returned an HTML document.